# Ansible-Failed to connect to the host via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to provison an EC2 instance and to install a LAMP server on it using Ansible from localhost. I have successfully provisioned the instance, but I was not able to install apache,php and mysql due to this error "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.".

OS: El Capitan 10.11.6

Ansible: 2.0.2.0

Here is the playbook: `---

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - "vars/{{ project_name }}.yml"
    - "vars/vpc_info.yml"
  tasks:
- name: Provision
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "xxxxxx"
    vpc_subnet_id: "xxxxxx"
    assign_public_ip: yes
    key_name: "xxxxxxx"
    instance_type: "t2.nano"
    image: "xxxxxxxx"

    wait: yes
    instance_tags:
      Name: "LAMP"
      class: "test"
      environment: "dev"
      project: "{{ project_name }}"
      az: a
    exact_count: 1
    count_tag:
      Name: "LAMP"
    monitoring: yes
  register: ec2a

- hosts: lamp
  roles:
    - lamp_server
```

The content of the ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
private_key_file=/Users/nico/.ssh/xxxxx.pem
```

The inventory:

```
lamp     ansible_ssh_host=<EC2 IP> ansible_user=ubuntu
```

The command used for running the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook  -i inventory  ec2_up.yml -e project_name="lamp_server"  -vvvv
```

Output:

```
 ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<xxxxxxxxxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/nico/.ssh/xxxxxxx.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ubuntu -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/nico/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r xxxxxxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1475186461.08-93383010782630 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1475186461.08-93383010782630 `" )'"'"''
52.28.251.117 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I have read a lot of threads regarding this error, but nothing helped me. :(

Comment: Problem solved: added -c paramiko at the end of the command that runs the playbook

Comment: `ansible-playbook  -i inventory  ec2_up.yml -e project_name="lamp_server"  -vvvv -c paramiko ` works

Comment: please add this to the answer for this question, and check the "accepted" box.  Nothing wrong answering and accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ansible-playbook -i inventory ec2_up.yml -e project_name="lamp_server" -vvvv **-c** paramiko